# IntelliJ says \b (backspace) is an illegal escape sequence inside a string literal. Why?

Tags: java, string, intellij-idea, literals

I have this piece of code

```
private static final Pattern controlChars = Pattern.compile(
        "[\u0001-\u0008\u000B\u000C\u000E-\u001F\u007F]");
```

and IntelliJ idea (2016.3) puts a red squiggle under `\u0008` saying it's an illegal/unsupported escape sequence. Changing it to any of `\b`, `\010` or `\x08` has no effect.

What I don't get is that the code builds and runs without a problem. Any idea what's the issue?

Comment: Using IntelliJ 2016.3.4 with Cursive, and can't reproduce. Backspaces don't work in the REPL, but they aren't underlined for me.

Comment: when you do `\u0008` it replaces that code with that characters. e.g. if you use `\u000a` it becomes a newline.

Comment: No error indication in Eclipse

Comment: I can reproduce in 2016.3.4

Comment: The easiest way to resolve this is to double the backslashes.  Meaning, instead of placing literal control characters in your string, use the six characters `\\u0001`, which Pattern will interpret as a escape in a regular expression.  See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum .

Comment: I get the same warning with `\K` in my php file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bug in the RegExp support. It is fixed in [IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1 Public Preview](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2017/02/intellij-idea-2017-1-public-preview-java-9-debugger-vcs-search-editor-and-many-more/).

You can remove the (harmless) error by positioning the text cursor on the error, typing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and invoking `Un-inject Language/Reference`. However this will also disable all other RegExp features on this literal.

Comment: Is there a way to "un-inject" just for one specific pattern (as opposed to disabling the feature completely)?

Comment: You could extract the pattern into a separate `String` variable and annotate that variable with `@org.intellij.lang.annotations.Language("TEXT")`